# How to rename all images together in OS X Mavericks?

Tags: macos

I am looking for the easy way to rename all images, or other groups of multiple files, together in OS X Mavericks.

Is it possible with Preview or any other standard OS X application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Automator

You can use OS X's **Automator.app** to quickly rename batches of images. The Actions you want are:

- Get Selected Finder Items
- Rename Finder Items

Using this approach you can rename files, change the case, or append/remove specific parts of the original file name.

[image: Automator rename workflow]

You can create [droplet like applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087148/how-to-make-a-droplet-on-mac-osx-with-automator) using Automator to make the whole process a single drag-and-drop. Alternatively you can [set up a folder action](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_use_folder_actions_automator) to rename any image dropped into a folder.

To learn more about using Automator, see Apple's [Mac Basics: Automator](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2488).

Comment: Alternately you can save a workflow as a "Service" which is then available through Finder.  This is what I use to batch rename files.